# How do i sit 2 divs left and right of eachother

Tags: css, html

So what i am trying to accomplish is sitting `<div id="box">` left of and `<div id="box2">` right of
inside the container of `<div id="content">` I must mention they cannot be position:absolute; unless there's a way to make sure the `height:auto;` div doesn't lose it's height because my experience `position:absolute;` seems to be floating above the other content.

here's a direct link to show you whats happening. keep in mind this is a pure css layout with a php backbone

[Direct Link to Issue](http://designed.sytes.net/index.php?p=about)

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="box1">
<h2>Company Information</h2>
            <img src="images/photo-about.jpg" alt="" width="177" height="117" class="aboutus-img" />
            <p color="FF6600">
            some content here
            </p>
    </div>
<div id="clear"></div>
    <div id="box" style="width:350px;">
            <h2>Availability</h2>
            <p>
            some more content here
            </p>
    </div>
<div id="clear"></div>
        <div id="box2" style="width:350px;float:left;overflow: auto;">
            <h2>Our Commitment</h2>
            <p> 
              some content here
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you looking for a fixed width layout or an elastic one?

Comment: What about the div with id "box"? In between the two?

Comment: the content is being loaded using $_get which is being in to a set width /auto height layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What `float` does is gives your element priority placement to the left-most edge of its containing div, at the expense of other inline elements on the page. It was originally intended for things like images placed alongside text (so the text could wrap around them).

If you want to float two elements next to each other, you can do so using `float:left;` and `float:right;`, and contain them in another div so other elements don't try to squeeze around them (or make sure the next element on deck has the `clear:both;` on it). In their containing div (if you're using one), use `overflow:auto` to automatically expand it to fit around those divs, as well. Make sure you also give the floating `div`s a width, otherwise they will automatically expand to fill the width of their parent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to "float"  your divs. Set a width on the divs, float them left or right, and be sure to clear after them so you don't get unintended fill-in by other elements. Use statements like the following within your CSS classes/IDs.

```
float:left;
width:WHATEVERpx;
```

...

```
float:right;
width:WHATEVERpx;
```

...

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: see i tried that and it did not work as expected the one on float right `box2` floated right but hung below `box` instead of sitting beside

Comment: box should be floated left. box2 floated right. your <div id="clear"> should not be between them. Further, you have that ID in the HTML twice. IDs should be used once per page. If you need reuse, make it a class instead.

Comment: But you'll need the floating divs before the content div. See @kgiannakakis

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a three column layout. This is more complex than you may think. You may get it easily with a simple example, but if you start adding headers or footers and having the columns expand with content,it will get tricky.

I suggest reading this [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/) to get some ideas.

Comment: i don't think that's it I'll post a link in my question

Comment: In the article the author discusses how to get to the solution. You **should** read it thoroughly. If you need a quick answer, see the example the author leaves in the end of the article: http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_4.html (But read the article nevertheless.)